# Replace only uncomment string with str_replace in php

Tags: php

log.php

```
define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.6666.com' );
//define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.6666.com' );
define ( 'COMPANY_FAX', 'asdfffff' );
```

My string replace code....

```
$config_old_arr[0] = " define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.6666.com' )";
$config_new_arr[0] = " define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.NEW.com' )";

$config_new_file_content = str_replace($config_old_arr, $config_new_arr, $logfilecontent);
```

After run my code...
change New log.php file

logNew.php

```
define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.NEW.com' );
//define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.NEW.com' );
define ( 'COMPANY_FAX', 'asdfffff' );
```

but i want to change only value in not-comment line(line No.1) so result string want to be as below

logNew.php

```
define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.NEW.com' );
//define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.6666.com' );
define ( 'COMPANY_FAX', 'asdfffff' );
```

i like to use str_replace() function but that method may be not suitable for this problem
Anyone know solution for this problem please help to me.

Comment: For that to really work you need a proper PHP parser. Isn't there an easier solution to the whole thing in the first place?

Comment: but cant you just: $config_old_arr[0] = " //define ( 'COMPANY_WEB', 'www.6666.com' )";                 Is there a space as a first char on every line ?

Comment: is the comment ever an any other format, or always starting with " //"

Comment: Is that possible to use preg_replace() function instead of str_replace() function now i want to really single line comment(//) escape. But i hope to improve my function for mulitline comment(/* */) escape string replacement

Answer (score -1):

use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to check the first 2 chars of the string

//$linetocheck = line to replace

```
if (substr($linetocheck, 0, 2) == "//") {

    //the first 2 chars are //

}
```

Comment: There are so many more ways to comment, including just indenting the line by one space.

Comment: indenting the line by one space., please explain ?

Comment: yes i didnt notice the space actually so it would be  if (substr($linetocheck, 0, 2) == " //") {              the poster shows a space in his replace code, but not in his logNew.php excerp ..

Comment: No! The point is that there may be a space or not. Or 10. Or 5. The comment *may* be `/* */` instead of `//`. There are so many variations for what a comment may look like!

Comment: sorry i didnt see anywhere where he said the comment would be in any other format than the one he posted .

Comment: I have to admit I'm making assumptions here, but if the file would be a fixed format he could just remove the commented line to begin with, I'd think.